# How to make square sides curved like Cylinder?

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view

I need to know how to make curved sides of square ( cube mesh ) just like sphere

I have square empty from inside like that :

[image]

When I make bevel just the vertex become rounded but the sides edges still not curved like that :

[image]

I want to make side edges curved like a cylinder just like that :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Start with a plane.  Tab into *Edit Mode*, select the face and press <kbd>X</kbd> and select *Only Faces*.  This leaves you with 4 verts connected by edges.

[image]

Tab out of *Edit Mode* and go to the menu item *Object* > *Convert To* > *Curve*.

Then in *Object Data Properties* expand *Geometry* and give it a *Bevel Depth*.

[image]

This should work for any continuous loop of verts.

[image: very describe]

It is possible to do this with more complex meshes, but they will require some work to look good since the corners only connect up on the longest continuous path.  Every other edge will be its own curve with disconnected control points.  Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

i would use the extra objects add-on which comes with blender.

[image]

here you can:

1. add elbow :

[image]

2. change angle + start + end length

[image]

then you get:

[image]

copy this 3 times, rotate and move, ready

after that Join them to one mesh and use the weld modifier to clean up your geometry.

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it is a perfect solution for my case but it is not perfect for another designs

Comment: Your question wasn‘t about any other design?!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution the bevel is connected with scale of object so in my case it the scal was ( 0.025, -0.75 , 0.65 ) so the bevel effect was small can't see it , to solve it :
1 - select object.

[image]

2 - press ( ctrl + A ).

[image]

3 - select scale. ( it will not affect the shape of object but will make scale ( 1,1,1 ).

[image]

4 - make bevel on it and the curve will be bigger than before.

[image]